# Compiling with XeLaTeX: problem with using Fontin font

Tags: xetex, fontspec

I want to compile a CV template and I have read in its description that it should be compiled with XeLaTeX, so I did it, however the font is not working. Specifically, there is a problem in line
`\setmainfont[SmallCapsFont = Fontin SmallCaps]{Fontin}`.
Latex shows the error `The font "Fontin" cannot be found.` Do you have any ideas how to fix it? Below is the code:

```
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Plasmati Graduate CV
% LaTeX Template
% Version 1.0 (24/3/13)
%
% This template has been downloaded from:
% http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com
%
% Original author:
% Alessandro Plasmati (alessandro.plasmati@gmail.com)
%
% License:
% CC BY-NC-SA 3.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/)
%
% Important note:
% This template needs to be compiled with XeLaTeX.
% The main document font is called Fontin and can be downloaded for free
% from here: http://www.exljbris.com/fontin.html
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article} % Default font size and paper size

\usepackage{fontspec} % For loading fonts
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont[SmallCapsFont = Fontin SmallCaps]{Fontin} % Main document font


\usepackage{xunicode,xltxtra,url,parskip} % Formatting packages

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor} % Required for specifying custom colors

\usepackage[big]{layaureo} % Margin formatting of the A4 page, an alternative to layaureo can be \usepackage{fullpage}
% To reduce the height of the top margin uncomment: \addtolength{\voffset}{-1.3cm}

\usepackage{hyperref} % Required for adding links   and customizing them
\definecolor{linkcolour}{rgb}{0,0.2,0.6} % Link color
\hypersetup{colorlinks,breaklinks,urlcolor=linkcolour,linkcolor=linkcolour} % Set link colors throughout the document

\usepackage{titlesec} % Used to customize the \section command
\titleformat{\section}{\Large\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{}[\titlerule] % Text formatting of sections
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{3pt}{3pt} % Spacing around sections

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty} % Removes page numbering

\font\fb=''[cmr10]'' % Change the font of the \LaTeX command under the skills section

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   NAME AND CONTACT INFORMATION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\par{\centering{\Huge John \textsc{Smith}}\bigskip\par} % Your name

\section{Personal Data}

\begin{tabular}{rl}
\textsc{Place and Date of Birth:} & Canada  | 20 November 1987 \\
\textsc{Address:} & 123 Broadway, City, State, Canada \\
\textsc{Phone:} & +1 111 1112\\
\textsc{email:} & \href{mailto:john@smith.com}{john@smith.com}
\end{tabular}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   WORK EXPERIENCE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Work Experience}

\begin{tabular}{r|p{11cm}}
\emph{Current} & 1\textsuperscript{st} year Analyst at \textsc{Lehman Brothers}, London \\
\textsc{Mar 2012} & \emph{Commodities Structured Trading}\\
& \footnotesize{Developed spreadsheets for risk analysis on exotic derivatives on a wide array of commodities (\textit{ags, oils, precious} and \textit{base metals}), managed blotter and secondary trades on structured notes, liaised with Middle Office, Sales and Structuring for bookkeeping.}\\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\

%------------------------------------------------

\textsc{Jul 2010-Oct 2011} & Summer Intern at \textsc{Intech Inc}, Chicago \emph{}\\
& \footnotesize{Received pre-placed offer from the Exotics Trading Desk as a result of very positive review. Rated ``\emph{truly distinctive}'' for Analytical Skills and Teamwork.}\\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\

%------------------------------------------------

\textsc{Jan-Mar 2011} & Computer Technician at \textsc{Buy More}, Burbank \emph{}\\
& \footnotesize{Worked in the Nerd Herd and helped to solve computer problems by asking customers to turn their computers off and on again.}
\end{tabular}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   EDUCATION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Education}

\begin{tabular}{rl} 
\textsc{July} 2012 & Master of Commerce in \textsc{Finance}, \textbf{The University of California}, Berkeley\\
& 110/110 \small\emph{First Class Honours} | Major: Quantitative Finance\\
& Thesis: ``Money is the Root of All Evil - Or is it?'' | \small Advisor: Prof. James \textsc{Smith}\\
&\normalsize \textsc{Gpa}: 8.0/9.0\hyperlink{grds}{\hfill | \footnotesize Detailed List of Exams}\\
&\\

%------------------------------------------------

\textsc{July} 2011& Undergraduate Degree in \textsc{}\textsc{Business Studies} \\&110/110 \small\emph{Commerce Specialization}, \normalsize\textbf{The University of California}, Berkeley\\
& Heavily specialized in mundane paperwork | \small Advisor: Stefano \textsc{Bonini}\\
&\normalsize \textsc{Gpa}: 7.5/9.0 \hyperlink{grds_usc}{\hfill| \footnotesize Detailed List of Exams}\\
&\\

%------------------------------------------------

\textsc{Fall} 2008 & Exchange Semester at \textbf{University of Southern California}, Los Angeles\\
& \textsc{Gpa}: 8.0/9.0 \hyperlink{grds_usc}{\hfill| \footnotesize Detailed List of Exams}\\
&\\

%------------------------------------------------

\textsc{July} 2006& \textbf{Liceo Classico ``E. Duni''}, Matera | Final Grade: 100/100
\end{tabular}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   SCHOLARSHIPS AND ADDITIONAL INFO
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Scholarships and Certificates}

\begin{tabular}{rl}
\textsc{Sept.} 2012 & Faculty of Science Masters Scholarship \footnotesize(\$30,000)\normalsize\\

\textsc{June} 2010 & {\textsc{Gmat}\textregistered}\setmainfont[SmallCapsFont=Fontin SmallCaps]{Fontin-Regular}: 730 (\textsc{q:50;v:39}) 96\textsuperscript{th} percentile; \textsc{awa}: 6.0/6.0 (89\textsuperscript{th} percentile)
\end{tabular}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   LANGUAGES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Languages}

\begin{tabular}{rl}
\textsc{English:} & Fluent\\

\textsc{Italian:} & Mothertongue\\

\textsc{French:} & Basic Knowledge\\
\end{tabular}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   COMPUTER SKILLS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Computer Skills}

\begin{tabular}{rl}
Basic Knowledge: & \textsc{php}, my\textsc{sql}, \textsc{html}, Access, \textsc{Linux}, ubuntu, {\fb \LaTeX}\setmainfont[SmallCapsFont=Fontin SmallCaps]{Fontin-Regular}\\

Intermediate Knowledge: & \textsc{vba}, Excel, Word, PowerPoint\\
\end{tabular}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   INTERESTS AND ACTIVITIES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Interests and Activities}

Technology, Open-Source, Programming\\
Paradoxes in Decision Making, Psychoanalysis, Behavioural Finance\\
Football, Travelling

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\newpage

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   GRADE TABLES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\par{\centering\Large \hypertarget{grds}{Master of Science in \textsc{Finance}}\par}\large{\centering Grades\par}\normalsize

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{lcc}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textsc{Exam}} & \textsc{Grade}&\textsc{Credit Hrs}\\ \hline
Corporate Finance (Valuation) & 25 & 6\\
Financial Statement Analysis & 28 & 6\\
Statistics & 27 & 6\\
Theory of Finance & 26 & 6\\
Quantitative Methods for Finance & 30 & 6\\
Econometrics & 24 & 6\\
Derivatives & 31 & 6\\
Management of Financial and Insurance Companies & 30 & 6\\
Business Law & 31 & 6\\
Investment Banking  & 28 & 6\\ \\       
Behavioral Models for Economics and Finance  & 29 & 6\\
Numerical Methods for Finance & 29 & 6\\
Advanced Derivatives & 30 & 6\\
Fixed Income (Advanced Methods) & 30 & 6\\ \\
English Language & 30 & 4\\
French Language & 31 &  4\\ 
Internship & & 8\\      
Final Thesis & & 20\\   
& Total & 120\\\cline{2-3}
&\textsc{Gpa}&\textbf{8.0}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\bigskip
\hrule
\bigskip

%------------------------------------------------

\bigskip

\par{\centering\Large \hypertarget{grds_usc}{Exchange Program at \textsc{usc}, Los Angeles}\par}\large{\centering Grades\par}\normalsize

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{lcc}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textsc{Exam}} & \textsc{Grade} & \textsc{Grade Points}\\
\hline
Corporate Financial Strategy & A & 4\\
Derivatives & A & 4\\
Money, Credit, and Banking & A & 4\\
Business Strategy & A- & 3.5\\
& &\\\cline{2-3}
& \textsc{Gpa} & \textbf{3.875}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

Comment: The error message is quite clear, it says that the font `Fontin` could not be found. This is either because you don't have it installed or because is is installed somewhere that XeLaTeX does not know.

Comment: Read your template. In the comments at the top it says where you can get the font.

Comment: Also, thanks for posting a Working Example, but there is much here that is irrelevant to reproduce the problem. Next time try to remove content that does not help on identifying the error. Put only what you thin is necessary to make other people have the same problem you have.

Answer (score 3):

On Linux, download the font files (including bold, italic, and regular) from the website mentioned in the comments to the directory `~/.fonts` and they should be installed for you.  No special privileges necessary.

On other OSes, you'll want to double-click on the font files as an administrator to install them. As a fallback, save them to the same directory as your source document and run the command from there.

Comment: Linux (Ubuntu, at least) also has a font installer that works with double-click.

Comment: Furthermore, many distributions have a package including Fontin. It is often named after the foundry, ejlibris.